# How to configure Virtual Box to handle multiple wireless network connections simultaneously

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

For testing purposes, I would like to set-up multiple (say 3-5 to begin with) virtual machines, be able to run them all at the same time, and have each access a unique wireless connection.

The machine has a standard USB wireless adapter.  We have access to a Verizon Wifi hot-spot that allows up to 10 unique connections.

The default Virtual Box configuration appears to have all instances using the same network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to distinguish between wired and wireless here, just used bridged networking for these VMs and select your wireless adapter as the parent adapter.